# Irish Visa or UK Visa or both?

Tags: visas, uk, transit, transit-visas, ireland

My husband and I are traveling to the UK for a wedding and then want to travel to Ireland to visit. I read up on BIVS and it looks like if I have a UK visa, I can travel to Ireland for a short stay.  However, I think I might have a big of a snag.

I bought flights to Dublin and then separately bought flights to the UK because it was cheaper.

I arrive in Dublin at 6:45 AM on the 26th of August. I have a flight from the same Airport at 1:45 PM to Edinburgh. Do I need an Irish Visa if I am not leaving the airport but getting on another flight to Edinburgh?

We plan on returning to Dublin on the 30th. Does the BIVS apply since I should have a UK visa for the same time period?

Me:
USA Green Card Holder and Permanent Resident with Indian Passport and Indian Citizenship

My schedule:

Flight from Atlanta Arrives in Dublin: Aug 26th.

Flight Leaves Dublin to Edinburgh Aug 26th.

Chill in Edinburgh

Flight from Edinburgh to Dublin August 30th.

Do all the Irish things.

Flight from Dublin to Atlanta September 5th.

Comment: It depends upon how long your visit to the Republic will be on the 30th.  Unclear...

Comment: I apologise. We want to spend 6 days in Dublin, before heading home. I've updated the original question as well.

Comment: 6 days is not covered by the rules. Travel to the Republic on a UK entry clearance is ok for a max of 3 days. That's how they define short-stay for those CTA type of situations.

Comment: BIVS is applicable to only people with certain nationalities be sure to check if yours is covered.

Comment: Looks like Citizen of India is covered. :)

Comment: @GayotFow thanks! Looks like I'll be applying for both visas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DUBLIN #1: You don't need a transit visa ([see](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html)).

EDINBURGH: You say you have or will obtain a visa. I presume this will be endorsed BIVS and will be valid for longer than 12 days (even though your time in UK is planned to be shorter than that).

DUBLIN #2: Your BIVS endorsed UK visa will cover you for Ireland, for as long as time remains on the (UK) visa. See [6 (c)](https://www.dfa.ie/media/embassychina/visas/BIVS-information-note-EN.pdf):

> The maximum stay in Ireland allowed to someone with an eligible UK visa is 90 days or the remaining period of validity of the person’s current leave to enter the United Kingdom, or, as the case may be, current leave to remain in the United Kingdom, whichever is the shorter.

Comment: Thanks man! I wound up applying for both but Ireland is slooooooow. Hopefully I'll get both back in time. UK promised 3 days.

Comment: +1, no disagreement at all. The BIVS has a different rule than the Standard Visitor Visa which provides a type of mobility that the SVV does not.  It's fine.